# JSExport not accessible from Javascript when using ScalaJSBundlerPlugin (webpack bundler)

Tags: webpack, scala.js

I am trying out the following hello world example of scalajs export found [here](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html):

```
@JSExportTopLevel("HelloWorld")
object HelloWorld {
  @JSExport
  def sayHello(): Unit = {
    println("Hello world!")
  }
}
```

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Example Scala.js application</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">

<script type="text/javascript" src="./../../../target/scala-2.13/scala-js-tutorial-fastopt.js"></script>
<script>
    HelloWorld.sayHello();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

which works fine.

Now if I try to use ScalaJSBundlerPlugin (which uses webpack under the hood), run `fastOptJS::webpack` and change the path to "./../../../target/scala-2.13/scalajs-bundler/main/scala-js-tutorial-fastopt-bundle.js", I get "HelloWorld is not defined".

How can I access HelloWorld once bundled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, scalajs-bundler uses the "Application" bundling mode, which can throw away top-level exports. As [the cookbook explains](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/cookbook.html#several-entry-points), when using `@JSExportTopLevel`, you need to the use the "LibraryAndApplication" bundling mode, using

```
webpackBundlingMode := BundlingMode.LibraryAndApplication()
```